# Fortran C-interoperable submodule procedure with bind(C) reports error when compiled by gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

Consider the following Fortran module `Foo_mod` and its submodule `Foo_smod`,

```
module CallbackInterface_mod

    abstract interface
        function getLogFunc4C_proc(ndim,Point) result(logFunc) bind(C)
            use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only : c_int32_t, c_double, c_int
            integer(c_int32_t), intent(in)  :: ndim
            real(c_double), intent(in)      :: Point(ndim)
            real(c_double)                  :: logFunc
        end function getLogFunc4C_proc
    end interface

end module CallbackInterface_mod

!***********************************************************************************************************************************
!***********************************************************************************************************************************

module Foo_mod

    interface
    module subroutine runFoo4C(ndim, getLogFuncFromC, inputString, inputStringLen) bind(C, name="runFoo")
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_int32_t, c_char, c_funptr, c_f_procpointer, c_size_t
        use CallbackInterface_mod, only: getLogFunc4C_proc
        implicit none
        integer(c_int32_t) , intent(in)                         :: ndim
        character(len=1, kind=c_char), dimension(*), intent(in) :: inputString
        integer(c_size_t) , intent(in)                          :: inputStringLen
        type(c_funptr), intent(in), value                       :: getLogFuncFromC
    end subroutine runFoo4C
    end interface

contains

    subroutine runFoo(ndim, getLogFunc, string)
        use CallbackInterface_mod, only: getLogFunc4C_proc
        use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env, only: RK => real64
        implicit none
        integer :: ndim
        procedure(getLogFunc4C_proc)    :: getLogFunc
        character(*), intent(in)        :: string
        real(RK)                        :: Point(ndim)
        character(:), allocatable       :: mystring
        Point = [1._RK,1._RK]
        write(*,*) "Hi again, this is a call from inside runFoo!"
        write(*,*) "getLogFunc(2,[1,1]) = ", getLogFunc(ndim,Point)
        write(*,*) "string = ", string
    end subroutine

end module Foo_mod

!***********************************************************************************************************************************
!***********************************************************************************************************************************

submodule (Foo_mod) Foo_smod

contains

    module subroutine runFoo4C(ndim, getLogFuncFromC, InputString, inputStringLen) bind(C, name="runFoo")

        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding, only: c_double, c_int32_t, c_char, c_funptr, c_f_procpointer, c_size_t
        use CallbackInterface_mod, only: getLogFunc4C_proc
        implicit none
        integer(c_int32_t) , intent(in)                         :: ndim
        character(len=1, kind=c_char), dimension(*), intent(in) :: InputString
        integer(c_size_t) , intent(in)                          :: inputStringLen
        type(c_funptr), intent(in), value                       :: getLogFuncFromC
        procedure(getLogFunc4C_proc), pointer                   :: getLogFunc
        real(c_double)                                          :: Point(ndim)
        character(:), allocatable                               :: inputString4tran
        integer                                                 :: i

        write(*,*) "InputString: ", InputString(1:inputStringLen)
        allocate( character(len=inputStringLen) :: inputString4tran )
        do i=1,inputStringLen
            inputString4tran(i:i) = InputString(i)
        end do
        write(*,*) "inputString4tran: ", inputString4tran

        ! associate the input C procedure pointer to a Fortran procedure pointer
        call c_f_procpointer(cptr=getLogFuncFromC, fptr=getLogFunc)
        Point = [1._c_double, 1._c_double]
        write(*,*) "getLogFunc(ndim=2, [1._c_double, 1._c_double]): ", getLogFunc( ndim, Point )

        call runFoo(ndim, getLogFunc, inputString4tran)

    end subroutine runFoo4C

end submodule Foo_smod
```

Now, this code seems like a perfectly sound Fortran module to me, and indeed it does compile and link successfully to C programs via Intel Fortran Compiler 2018, on both Windows and Linux, and runs correctly. However, when compiled by gfortran 7.3.0, it gives the following error:

```
gfortran -c ../Foo_mod.f90
../Foo_mod.f90:54:18:

submodule (Foo_mod) Foo_smod
                1
Error: BIND(C) attribute at (1) can only be used for variables or common blocks
```

The problem can be resolved if I remove the `bind(c)` attribute from the interface of the interoperable subroutine `runFoo4C()` in module `Foo_mod`, like the following,

```
...
module subroutine runFoo4C(ndim, getLogFuncFromC, inputString, inputStringLen) ! bind(C, name="runFoo")
...
```

However, the Intel Fortran compiler would then complain about the incompatibility of the subroutine's interface in module `Foo_mod` and the implementation of the subroutine in submodule `Foo_smod`. This seems to me  more like a bug in GFORTRAN, than programming mistake. But your comments are appreciated before I go on to report it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite clear to me that this is a gfortran bug related to submodules. As that's a fairly recent feature addition, it's not unexpected that there may be bugs here and there.

I will comment that when asking a question such as this here, you are strongly encouraged to provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Since you don't show the module that the submodule goes with, we can't verify the issue ourselves without unnecessary extra work.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for confirming the bug. The parent module `Foo_mod` is in fact given in my question, right before the submodule declaration. It should be enough to copy and paste the entire code given here into a file like `Foo_mod.f90` and compile it to see the error. One thing that I have not checked though is whether the bug persists in the newer GFORTRAN versions or not. But I don't have access to the newer versions at the moment.

Comment: the version I used if gfortran 7.3.0

Comment: Steve, on a separate issue, is the following statement standard conforming? "It is valid to have a Fortran procedure with the same name as the binding name of another Fortran C-interoperable procedure in the same module." An example of this is the interoperable subroutine `runFoo4C() bind(c,name=runFoo`, and subroutine `subroutine runFoo()` both of which live in the module `Foo_mod` in the example code above. or otherwise, if it is not, should I expect this code to break sometime in the future with some other compilers?

Comment: @King The key is whether subroutine runFoo has a "binding label" that is the same as what is created for runFoo4C. The standard says "a binding label shall not be the same as the global identifier of any other global entity, ignoring differences in case." (F2018, 19.2p2) It's not very likely that the module procedure runFoo will have a binding label of "runFoo" (plus any decoration that the companion C compiler would add). For example, in Intel Fortran on Windows, runFoo would be FOO_MOD_mp_RUN_FOO. That said, it's not a good idea to do this.

Comment: Note also that a module procedure's name is not a global identifier, or else you couldn't have a runFoo in any other module. But note that you can usually construct a binding label that duplicates another procedure, which would invalidate the program.

Comment: thanks Steve. The idea behind doing it was to make the subroutine `runFoo()` and its C-interoperable-wrapper `runFoo4C` have the same name, so that the user can call the subroutine with the same name from both languages (albeit with different sets of input arguments, which should not matter anyway).

Comment: The alternative that I had in mind was to have an `interface runFoo` block in the module for both the wrapper `runFoo4C() bind(C,name="runFoo")` and the original Fortran subroutine, now named `runFoo4tran()`. In this scenario, the wrapper's binding name `name=runFoo` would be the same as the interface block's name `interface runFoo`. I have not tested this with Intel yet.

Comment: Your first idea is fine. The second defines a generic name; I suppose you could have two module procedures in the generic, but I see no advantage to this. You don't want Fortran code to use the C version, and you'd have to have distinguishable argument lists, limiting you.